# Is it possible to classify a PDE using the method of characteristics?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I know that the method of characteristics is the technique to solve some PDEs. But I obtained an assignment to classify PDE (hyperbolic, elliptic or parabolic) using the very same method. I was wondering how to understand that the solution belongs to either an elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic PDE.

For instance the transport equation has a linear characteristic curve. But how do I know that this implies that the PDE itself is hyperbolic.

Comment: I don't know about parabolic equations, but elliptic equations do not have any real characteristics. So if there are characteristics at all, and you have a PDE which you know is one of those three (say, it's second order linear), then it's either parabolic or hyperbolic. I have only seen people study characteristics in the hyperbolic case, but I'm new to PDEs.

Comment: None that I know of. [This](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/111103021/12.pdf) is what I learned.